# How do I find dependencies causing class duplication?

Tags: android, gradle

When I build the android project, it show "Duplicate class" exception,

```
1 exception was raised by workers:   java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Duplicate class android.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1) and classes.jar(android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1)   
Duplicate class android.arch.core.executor.TaskExecutor found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1) and classes.jar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1)**
```

How could I find and fix what lib use duplicate class in my project?

app.Gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion ’28.0.3’

defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation ’org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31’api('com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.9.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
}
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0’
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.2’
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1' 
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1' 
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8'
implementation 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.1'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.10.11'
implementation project(':lib-zxing')
implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'
implementation 'com.github.lassana:continuous-audiorecorder:1.3.1'
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar'
implementation 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-2'
}
```

lib-zxing

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion ’28.0.3’

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}dependencies {
api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0’
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-2'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to exclude the arch Jar. First of all check where the duplicate comes from. You can see it if you print your dependency tree with a gradle task:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Then exclude the older arch Jar like you did for glide but with the correct exclude, for example:

```
implementation ('android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1') {
    exclude group: "android.arch.core"
}
```

Comment: It make me avoid duplicate android.arch.core exception, but it still Duplicate class com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat found in modules core-3.3.0.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0) and core_3.0.1.jar (core_3.0.1.jar)
  Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Binarizer found in modules core-3.3.0.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0) and core_3.0.1.jar (core_3.0.1.jar), How could I fix this exception?

Comment: It looks like another duplicate dependency. Try the same, as in my answer but for zxing.core. Also you have to work over your dependency. You include room in an alpha version but room is also available as a newer v2.0 version. And if you want to use a barcode scanner (zxing). You can use this one: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Answer (score 1):

You can use search everywhere dialog(Dialog that opens on pressing shift twice).

Simply copy class name and paste it in search dialog and it will show results in drop down. You can browse result and check for duplicate entries, Complete path of class will be displayed next to class name so you can find relative libraries and can safely exclude it from anyone of the library.

Comment: I find it in external, but I don't know what lib is it parent, is it possible to find it and make me can exclude it?

Comment: it will show the module name on the right side, by checking the module name you can identify which library it belongs